# Classification of curve data with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model

I have tabular dataset each row represent the curve, so goal is to filter out curves that do not follow Sigmoid function. Obviously first I can label the curves.

My question would be is machine learning (classification , LSTM ) applicable here or better than the conventional coding solution ?

Comment: Parameterize them in some way.  What if you try and fit a sigmoid (logistic) to each curve and use the parameters as features?  There are many examples of this and python scipy will fit the curve for you for arbitrary non-linear functions.  I would then look to cluster or try some kind of anomaly detection.

Comment: Each curve has 42 data points, may be I can use each of them as feature  ?

Comment: But isn't this fine?  When it's not a sigmoid, you will get parameters that are different.  Have you tried plotting the parameters that result in a 2D space for instance?  I bet you get some nice clusters.

Comment: @neuroguy123 parameters you mean `popt` or  `pcov`

Comment: Yes, what happens if you plot the 4 parameters?  Do they distinguish what you want?

Comment: plot against what ?, if you see update 2, in some curves I get very good fitness , even it  is not sigmoid

Answer (score 4):

One option is [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). Fit a sigmoid function to the data and decide if the quality of fit is below a threshold for [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).